# Ubuntu Screen Lock

Tags: ubuntu, display

When I lock screen on Ubuntu, I want transmission to open up automatically, and when I unlock the screen, transmission should pause itself or die.

I have searched a lot but cannot find anything worthwhile.

I thought of a solution, of creating a cron job and using `gnome-screensaver-command -q` and starting up transmission, seems like a wastage. Is there a better way (something event based)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dbus to get hold of the events when the screensaver activates or deactivates, see [here](http://live.gnome.org/GnomeScreensaver/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Is_there_a_way_to_perform_actions_when_the_screensaver_activates_or_deactivates.3F__Or_when_the_session_becomes_idle.3F).

You can use `transmission-remote` to control transmission from the command line, as shown [here](https://forum.transmissionbt.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=3030).

Therefore you will end up with a perl script along the lines of:

```
my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'\"";

$starttrans="transmission-remote --torrent all --start";
$stoptrans="transmission-remote --torrent all --stop";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
    if (m/^\s+boolean true/) {
        starttrans;
    } elsif (m/^\s+boolean false/) {
        stoptrans;
    }
}
```

(I'm writing this in Windows with no perl/ transmission so it is almost certainly not going to work properly.)

Comment: thanks for pointing in the right direction, but i don't know perl so cant check it right now. And, this for "member='SessionIdleChanged'". I want when I lock the screen manually.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I have come up with a python script which does what I want using [dbus-monitor](http://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-screensaver/docs/gnome-screensaver.html#gs-signal-ActiveChanged)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if "boolean true" in line:
        print os.system("transmission -m &")
    elif "boolean false" in line:
        print os.system("pkill transmission")
```

On the shell,

```
dbus-monitor type=signal,\
             interface=org.gnome.ScreenSaver,\
             member=ActiveChanged\
             | ./script.py  &
```